# If possible calculate the norms of the following linear forms.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let  be $I$ and $d$ defined as $$I:f\to\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx \\ d:f\to f(0)$$ on $\mathcal{C}^1[-1,1]$. Check if the linear forms are continous with respektive to the norms $\|\text{ }\|_{\infty}, \|\text{ }\|_{L_1}, \|\text{ }\|_{L_2}, \|\text{ }\|_{\mathcal{C}^1}$, and if so, calculate the norm.

I haven't quite understood norms in this way and so I have been searching all day on the internet for somekind of hint that could help me solve this problem. Sadly I wasn't lucky, so could someone here help me? Hints would be nice, so I can come to the solution myself.

Comment: It would help by at least writing down the definition of continuity with respect to each norm.

Answer (score 1):

The question of continuity is one of "can we put the limit inside?" So what this question asks is:

> "if $f_n\to f$ in the following norms, then is it true that $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1f_n\to\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 f$?"

So for the first one, if $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then is it true that $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1f_n\to\int_{-1}^1f$?

Well, yes, the sequence is of uniformly continuous functions, so $|f_n-f|\le M$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$, hence LDCT implies

$$\left|\int_{-1}^1f_n-f\right|\le\int_{-1}^1|f_n-f|\to 0$$

For the norm, you want to find

> $$\sup_{|f|\le 1}\left|\int_{-1}^1f\right|$$

but clearly $f\equiv 1$ gives the max, and a norm of $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 1=2$.

Similarly for the evaluation map we have $f_n(0)\to f(0)$ just by pointwise convergence, never mind the added bonus of uniform convergence. Similarly you want

> $$\sup_{|f|\le 1}f(0)$$

and clearly $f(0)=1$ is as large as it can be, regardless of other points, so $d$ has norm $1$.

Can you see how this works for the others?

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't get what you have done there. I mean, I understood you have proven that $f_n\to f$ then $\int_{-1}^{1}f_n\to\int_{-1}^{1}f$, but I haven't seen that it was used in respective to the other norms... Or if you do it that way then you have proved sth generilzed what holds for all other norms?

And for the integral, don't you get for $f\equiv 1$ that $int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=f(1)-f(-1)?

Comment: @HeatTheIce well you asked a bunch of questions which would involve a ton of writing. Typically on MSE we answer one question at a time, and you show all the work you've done so far. So I split the difference, rather than just giving you a not-too-helpful hint as some would, I worked out one case for you. Now if you try the others and perhaps have some work to show you could start another topic and you'd likely get help if you were unable to figure them out on your own from that work. As to your last question, remember integrating means take an antiderviative so $\int 1 = x\bigg|_{-1}^1=2$.